# change color background textview for loops

Tags: android, textview

`TextView[] Casilla = new TextView[42];

```
    Casilla[0] = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.TxtVCasilla1);
    Casilla[1] = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.TxtVCasilla2);
    Casilla[2] = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.TxtVCasilla3);
    Casilla[3] = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.TxtVCasilla4);
    Casilla[4] = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.TxtVCasilla5);
    Casilla[5] = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.TxtVCasilla6);
```

...

```
for (int i = CasillaInicio; i < CasillaFin; i++) {
        int diacasilla = (i-CasillaInicio)+1;
        String enteroString = Integer.toString(diacasilla);
        Casilla[i].setText(enteroString);
    }

        for (int i = PrimeraManana; i < CasillaFin; i++) {

        if (Casilla[i].getText()== "") {

        }
        else {  for (int m = i; m <CasillaFin; m++){


                Casilla[i].setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.casilla_manana_xhdpi));
                m++;
                Casilla[i].setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.casilla_tarde_xhdpi));`
```

I'm doing a calendar for work, I need to change the background color depending on the TextView shifts and this takes a cycle of 2 morning, 2 afternoons, 2 nights and 4 breaks. as might make these loops and change textViews I tried but I change them all at the same color.

this is the code I have done but I do not know how many loops have to make or how to make them to change the boxes in the cycles that I have put before.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit and post the code you have so far showing what isn't working as you want?

Comment: why `m++` inside `m` for loop?

Comment: is a test to leave a colorless TextView give m + + to make a leap in the loop